# Check string contain the words with condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i want to check that if string contains **brandname** and **category** than first `if` statement should execute. if string contains **brandname**,**category** and **priceRange** than `else if` statement should be execute.if i run code like this it is always executing the first `if` because the condition is true at first `if` as well as it contains the priceRange.i hope that you understand it!

```
string fullQueryString = "brandName category priceRange";

if (fullQueryString.Contains("brandNamee") & fullQueryString.Contains("category"))
{
   string firstStatement = "first if ";
}
else if (fullQueryString.Contains("brandNamee") & fullQueryString.Contains("category") & fullQueryString.Contains("priceRange"))
{
   string secondStatement = "the else if";
}
else
{
   string other = "something else";
}
```

Comment: Have you thought about switching the order of if statements?

Comment: @Hirwo yeah you are right i thought it but did not use it lols.... it works by switching the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest a few changes, all of which are included in the below code example:

First, a typo: you are checking for "brandNamee" (with 2 "e"s when you need 1 "e")

Second, in the logic, you would want to progress from most restrictive to least restrictive:

1. IF we have all 3, do this
2. We don't have all 3? Okay, IF we have only 2, do this
3. ELSE, do this

```
string result = "";
string fullQueryString = "brandName category priceRange";
if (fullQueryString.Contains("brandName") & fullQueryString.Contains("category") & fullQueryString.Contains("priceRange"))
{
    result = "first if ";
}
else if (fullQueryString.Contains("brandName") & fullQueryString.Contains("category"))
{
    result = "the else if";
}
else
{
    result = "something else";
}

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Another important change is declaring the `result` variable outside of the `If` statements so that the string values assigned within the `If` statements are accessible outside the `If` statements.